# Why is my Primary Key slowing down my queries?

Tags: sql-server, performance, indexing

i'm using SQL Server 2008 and, in one of my tables, i implemented a (clustered) primary key on its identifier. Here's the table description:

Identifier:
 - IdentifierId int NOT NULL PK
 - Alias nvarchar(200)
 - DataType int NOT NULL

I made two indexes: one for Alias and another one for DataType.
However, I just noticed something strange. 
When running the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM IDENTIFIER WHERE DataType = 1
```

The query actually runs slower with the indexes and the primary key than without them; it takes approximately 10 seconds longer! The indexes are not fragmented - i checked - and i'm also using this

```
GO
CHECKPOINT;
GO
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS;
GO
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE;
GO
```

before the query itself.

This table is rather large, having several million entries on it. Indexes and PKs play a vital role on most queries, but in this case i can't understand why the query is running **slower** with them. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

EDIT: The execution plan shows that only the clustered index is being used and the DataType variable currently goes up to 150.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the execution plans produced?

Comment: How selective is the data type column? (i.e. how many values can that column be)?

Comment: Just answered: only the clustered index and the datatype only goes from 1 to 150

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a composite non-clustered covering index on `DataType` with included column `Alias`, and remove the individual indexes on `Alias` and `DataType` columns:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX NC_DataType_I_Alias 
    ON tblIdentifier(DataType) INCLUDE (Alias)
```

Answer (score 7):

When you select *, the system will still needs to get every column.  So the optimizer will often determine that it is quicker to use the clustered index scan (remember a clustered index is not really an index - it's just data organized by the order specified) than to use a seek on a different index combined with a bookmark lookup based on primary key to retrieve the additional rows.

So the key to performance is to have a non-clustered index (this is a bad name, really, since non-clustered indexes often far outperform clustered indexes) and `INCLUDE` additional columns in the index so that it becomes `covering`.  In the case of pre-SQL Server 2005, you simply have to add the columns to the end of the index.

So, basically, a primary key is good, but should not necessarily determine your choice of clustering, and you will generally need to rely on non-clustered indexes (with appropriately `INCLUDE`ed columns) for performance on most selective operations, with the clustered index designed for the least selective and most commonly sorted case.